# How to create Capillaries in Blender?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I tried extruding a single vert to create a rough skeleton of the capillary network. Then used Subdiv modifier to smooth it out and then used the skin modifier to create the vessels. But this results in weird shading issues.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this ? Is there any better method to create similar looking blood capillaries ?

Blender ver.: 2.92

Comment: You probably just need an additional *Subdiv* after skinning